# pip errors regarding permission, can this be fixed?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use `pip`, and every time I run a command to `install` or `upgrade`, I see this type of error (`OSError`).

I don't like having to sudo just to install packages, is this required?

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils'
```

Comment: If you don't want to use sudo, then use virtualenv.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess so it is normal to have to do this?

Comment: Yes. By default, the python standard library and packages you add are installed in an administrative area.

Comment: In practice, I use homebrew to install a [non-system] version of Python in `/usr/local`, then `chown` `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to modify a location shared amongst all users. You can't do that without `sudo`-ing, for good reason (otherwise, people could replace, say, `python`, with a program that deletes all your user data, or copies it to their home folder for perusal, etc.).

If you want to only make the changes for yourself, not others, you can pass `pip` the `--user` argument to install to `~/.local` such that the new package is installed only for you, not other users.

Virtual environments are another option, but that's overkill to an extent (an active virtual environment isolates you completely from even the system `site-packages` directory, so you must individually install all packages again if they're needed).

Comment: is that the best practise?  I am the only use of the laptop.

Comment: @Blankman: If you're the only user, then it doesn't really matter which approach you take. That said, if a second user ever arises (including, say, processes run under restricted accounts for security), installing with `--user` means they won't see the new package, a system-wise install (which requires elevated permissions to perform, e.g., from `sudo`) would ensure everyone sees it.

Comment: Not only if He is the only user, I'm the only user on my machine but I use several virtual enviroments to keep isolated development envs. the issue is already answered, as the question was not "which  is the better way to...". as @David K. Hess  mentioned, I also recommend `virtualenv`

Comment: @RafaelAguilar: Virtual environments for isolated development purposes, certainly. For "I would like to install this package and have it generally available", virtual environments are the opposite of what you want.

Comment: @RafaelAguilar you are making the assumption that the OP is using the package(s) for development. This may or may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Linux and Mac OS come with their own packaged python interpreter, and it is not advisable to use them for your development purpose. Start using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), a tool to create isolated Python environments in which you can install any packages, test installation of your own libraries and much more without affecting the systemwide installed python environment. Check out their site for tutorials on how to install, create and run scripts in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable).